# On the numeric range of a long double

Tags: c, double, long-integer

### Compiling and running this code:

```
// List the range of the long double.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
int main() {
  printf("Long double: %Lg - %Lg\n", LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX);
}
```

### Gives this result:

`Long double: 3.3621e-4932 - 1.18973e+4932`

Yet this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
int main() {
  long double ld = 1.18973e+4932;
  printf("Longest double: %Lg", ld);
}
```

Gives this warning when compiled:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -o fj -Wall -Wno-format-overflow -g r2.c  -lm
```

```
r2.c:4:3: warning: floating constant exceeds range of ‘double’ [-Woverflow]
    4 |   long double ld = 1.18973e+4932;
      |   ^~~~
```

However, if you compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
int main() {
  long double ld = LDBL_MAX;
  printf("Longest double: %Lg\n", ld);
}
```

It compiles and runs:

`Longest double: 1.18973e+4932`

What's going on here? It should accept the numerical limit that was listed in the first program, but it does just fine with the LDBL_MAX version of it.

### My compiler:

gcc --version

gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110

### My computer:

AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics

CPU MHz:  3057.560

BogoMIPS: 7785.19

CPU cache size: 512 KB

Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Comment: Note that `LDBL_MIN` is not the smallest non-zero `long double` - it is the smallest _normal_ `long double`.  `LDBL_TRUE_MIN` is the smallest `long double`, a sub-normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1.18973e+4932` is an out-of-range `double` constant.
`LDBL_MAX` is an in range `long double` constant.

Make the floating point constant a `long double` by appending an `L`.
Lower case `l` is an option too, yet harder to distinguish from `1`.

```
// long double ld = 1.18973e+4932;
long double ld = 1.18973e+4932L;  // Yet this is not quite the max

// max value better with adequate precision as 
long double ld = 1.18973149535723176502e+4932L;

// Should print the same.
printf("Longest double: %.*Lg\n", LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG, ld);
printf("Longest double: %.*Lg\n", LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG, LDBL_MAX);
```

When coding near the limits, consider hex notation for better control in rounding issues.

```
long double ld = 1.1897315e+4932L;              --> Infinity
long double ld = 1.18973149535723177e+4932L;    --> Infinity
long double ld = 1.18973149535723176506e+4932L; --> Infinity
//               1.18973149535723176502e+4932L

long double ld = 0x1.fffffffffffffffep+16383L;
```

Comment: The type of an unsuffixed integer constant depends on part on its value; if `INT_MAX==32767`, then `32767` is of type `int` and `32768` is of type `long`. Floating-point constants follow different rules (which can cause some confusion). An unsuffixed floating-point constant is always of type `double`. If you need `float` or `long double`, add a suffix.

Comment: @KeithThompson Good points.  Also note that OP had sufficient warnings enabled to receive "warning: floating constant exceeds range ...".  Kudos for OP doing so and a fresh positive change from many FP questions.